# How to let the apache(2.4.7) know to use newly installed (upgraded) php version?

Tags: apache2, php

I am running the Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and have upgraded the PHP 5.5.9 to PHP 5.6.30-1 as shown in the below: (Notice also that I came to two versions: php5 and php.)

```
$ php5 -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 (cli) (built: Jul 28 2016 19:31:33)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.30-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

I have also noticed the directory (`/etc/php`) is empty except the 5.6/ as shown:

```
$ ls /etc/php5
apache2/  cgi/  cli/  conf.d/  mods-available/
$ ls /etc/php
5.6/
```

And, my `phpinfo()` still shows the earlier version of the php even after I installed (or, upgraded) the php 5.6.30. 
I can't include images because I am new to this forum page. I thought it would be clearer with the output of the `phpinfo()`

How can I let the apache2 (2.4.7) know that I like to use the newly installed PHP 5.6.30?

Comment: How did you install PHP 5.6? Did you install the Apache module as well?

Answer (score 0):

As far I recall you need upgrade `libapache2-mod-php5` package as well. Actually, I'd upgraded whole system once on it:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have dist-upgrade-ed but now, it seems the php is not working. I simply cannot get the phpinfo() displayed.<br/> Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for my mis-info. The php works but the upgrade issue still exists (as in my origitnal post).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out for the posted problem.

1. Ensure that /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.6.{conf,load}
2. Run a2enmod php5.6 (if you have php5 enabled, do a2dismod php5 first)
3. Check the PHP version with the phpinfo() from your browser.

Thank you all for your comments.
Woogon